# Killer abducts woman (witness to a killing?). Her attempt to escape from the hotel room is foiled by a door wedge. Ambiguous ending

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

This may have been a short story in an Alfred Hitchcock story collection, as I read a lot of those as a child. It would have been read prior to 2000, after 1988 or so, since that's when I started reading books meant for older individuals, including those on my father's shelf, and probably somewhere in the early 1990s based on my recollection of it. The beginning of the story has a male contract killer kill someone with a silenced pistol (I remember the story specifically comparing the sound of the silenced pistol to a popping balloon, which is [generally inaccurate](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodSilencer)), only to be spotted by a woman, who he abducts. I think he takes her to a hotel, and they have a conversation about who they are and why he does what he does (I don't remember particulars) and then, late that night, while she believes him to be asleep, she tries to exit the room, only to find the door won't budge. He sits up in the bed (I can't recall if there was any implication they slept together) and shows her the nearly invisible little rubber wedge he'd used to ensure the door couldn't be opened, and then I think the story ends with her wondering if he's going to kill her now.